# Не передаются css-свойства через toggleClassJquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Есть код:

```
$('#more').on('click', function(){
$('#bottomText').toggleClass('bottomTextToogle');
});
```

Который по клику на элемент с идентификатором **more** должен задать элементу с идентификатором **bottomText** класс **bottomTextToogle** , если такого у него нет, иначе - удалить его.
Данный css-класс имеет довольно скудный набор свойств:

```
.bottomTextToogle{ 
height:inherit;
overflow:visible;
}
```

Проверяем, что есть в действительности (до и после клика соответственно):[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. класс добавился, но не его свойства? Чойтатакое? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Показанный на скриншоте селектор `#no5 .tt3 div` гораздо сильнее, чем какой-то `.bottomTextToogle`. Собственно на этом всё.

Comment: истинно так! благодарствую, вопрос решён)м

Comment: слабее-сильнее)) специфичнее, выше приоритет, автору вопроса читать http://htmlbook.ru/samcss/kaskadirovanie